# HDD not recognised on startup unless manual sighting via file mgr

Tags: hard-drive

now running Ubuntu 18.04.3 with 110GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. ubuntu installed on SSD. (just ubuntu not dual OS)
After booting if I open a desktop shortcut to a file located on HDD I get error message stated cant find path. 
I need to open up file manager> other locations> data
This then allows the system to "see" that there's an HDD and the shortcut will work.
What can be done to make Ubuntu automatically know there is an HDD? TIA.

Comment: Did you have the HDD to your file system table (`/etc/fstab`) so it gets auto-mounted?  or do anything to ensure it's auto-mounted? (*there are many ways of achieving this result, editing fstab is just my preferred way*)  It sounds like you didn't.

Comment: What is the path used in your shortcut?

Comment: Hi, when I click properties of the file it shows this:
/media/nick/Data/Documents/Reference Library

I'm not sure if there is automount, I assume not. I got a local IT company to do the install because I thought they'd do it right...
Do you know a simple way to check / perform this?